# Phalcon Migration - How to remove database columns?

Tags: php, database, migration, phalcon

I am looking at creating a phalcon migration that will remove some columns from a table within my database, however I am struggling to understand how we remove the columns and the documentation doesn't seem to reference how to do this?

Here is how the columns have been added to the database in a previous migration.

```
new Column(
    'automatic_adjust_status',
    [
        'type' => Column::TYPE_VARCHAR,
        'size' => 255,
        'after' => 'manual_price'
    ]
),
new Column(
    'automatic_adjust_amount',
    [
        'type' => Column::TYPE_VARCHAR,
        'size' => 255,
        'after' => 'automatic_adjust_status'
    ]
),
new Column(
    'automatic_adjust_type',
    [
        'type' => Column::TYPE_VARCHAR,
        'size' => 255,
        'after' => 'automatic_adjust_amount'
    ]
),
new Column(
    'automatic_adjust_after',
    [
        'type' => Column::TYPE_VARCHAR,
        'size' => 255,
        'after' => 'automatic_adjust_type'
    ]
),
```

If anyone can advise me how to remove these columns, that would be great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to sort it :) Here is the code:

https://docs.phalcon.io/3.4/en/db-layer#altering-tables

```
    $this->getConnection()->dropColumn(
        'lists',
        $this->db,
        'automatic_adjust_status'
    );

    $this->getConnection()->dropColumn(
        'lists',
        $this->db,
        'automatic_adjust_amount'
    );

    $this->getConnection()->dropColumn(
        'lists',
        $this->db,
        'automatic_adjust_type'
    );

    $this->getConnection()->dropColumn(
        'lists',
        $this->db,
        'automatic_adjust_after'
    );
```